# What is the specific difference between Bitmap from BitmapFactory.decodeFile and BitmapFactory.decodeResource in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I use this photo filter from https://github.com/Zomato/AndroidPhotoFilters to develop my app

this is my code when i got IllegalStateExpression

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>                                                                                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixels(Bitmap.java:1556)
>                                                                                  at com.zomato.photofilters.imageprocessors.ImageProcessor.doBrightness(ImageProcessor.java:45)
>                                                                                  at com.zomato.photofilters.imageprocessors.subfilters.BrightnessSubfilter.process(BrightnessSubfilter.java:28)
>                                                                                  at com.zomato.photofilters.imageprocessors.Filter.processFilter(Filter.java:88)
>                                                                                  at org.d3ifcool.photostation.PhotoEditorActivity.onCreate(PhotoEditorActivity.java:103)
>                                                                                at org.d3ifcool.photostation.PhotoEditorActivity.onCreate(PhotoEditorActivity.java:104)

on `Bitmap image1 = mMyFilter.processFilter(mOriginalImage);`

```
BitmapFactory.Options mOriginalOption = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    mOriginalOption.inSampleSize = 2;
    Bitmap mOriginalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, mOriginalOption);

    mMyFilter = SampleFilters.getBlueMessFilter();
    Bitmap image1 = mMyFilter.processFilter(mOriginalImage);

    loadFilter(image1);
```

But it'll success if i use this code

```
context = this.getApplicationContext();
    Bitmap outputImage = mMyFilter.processFilter(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_bg_main_activity), 640, 640, false));

    loadFilter(outputImage);
```

And this the methode from the documentation

```
public Bitmap processFilter(Bitmap inputImage) {
    Bitmap outputImage = inputImage;
    if (outputImage != null) {
        for (SubFilter subFilter : subFilters) {
            try {
                outputImage = subFilter.process(outputImage);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError oe) {
                System.gc();
                try {
                    outputImage = subFilter.process(outputImage);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError ignored) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return outputImage;
}
```

Why cant i use the BitmapFactory.decodeFile?
I need to pick the image from SD Card, not from the drawable resouce.

Does .decodeFile and .decodeResource have a different type of Bitmap?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: have you read the docs for both methods?

Comment: `i got IllegalStateExpression at the 6th line` Please show complete message and tell wich code is on that line.

Comment: Probably something is wrong with your path so `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` returns null as the doc says `If the specified file name is null, or cannot be decoded into a bitmap, the function returns null.`. Then you tries to process a filter on a null object (line 6) so you get the Exception

Comment: By any chance did you give permission to your app to access external files?

Comment: @greenapps i already edited my question, check it out

Comment: According to the docs, the decodeFile methods throws IllegalStateException "if inPreferredConfig is HARDWARE and inMutable is set, if the specified color space is not RGB, or if the specified color space's transfer function is not an ICC parametric curve". So, you probably have some wrong configuration inside your options (which is strange because you've just created it. Maybe it's a device problem?)

Comment: @Eselfar already have that permission, i'll check for the null pointer now

Comment: @GabrielCosta The decodeFile is fine, the exception is below that as decodeFile has returned a null value

Comment: @GabrielCosta yeah the decodeFile is fine, but i have no idea why i cant put the bitmap on .processFilter method

Comment: @Eselfar the .decodeFile is fine, i just wondering why i cant get that bitmap into .processFilter

Comment: `the exception is below that as decodeFile has returned a null value – Eselfar 6 mins ago`. Well then why do you continue if the bitmap instance is null? You should stop then of course.

Comment: So your Bitmap is not null? In your second example, the one you said it works, you do `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` before giving the bitmap to the filter. Did you try to do the same in the first case?

Comment: @greenapps I'm not OP

Comment: Sorry... am a bit confused now.

Comment: @greenapps I said the decodeFile method is fine as the Exception is not at this line. So because OP get a NullPointerException I thought it was because decodeFile has returned null. But apparently it's not the case. But still, the error is with the filter.

Comment: @Eselfar oh dude, you hit the spot, i forgot to create the scale for those bitmap, thanks a lot ! :D

Comment: @greenapps thanks for ur attention on this question :D

Comment: @Eselfar can u post some answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as the Bitmap returned by `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` is not null, your problem is with the `processFilter` method.

In the second example (the one you say it works), you create a scaled Bitmap before calling `processFilter`. So in order to solve your issue, you should probably do:

```
BitmapFactory.Options originalOption = new BitmapFactory.Options();
originalOption.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, originalOption );

if (bitmap != null) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 640, 640, false);
    mMyFilter = SampleFilters.getBlueMessFilter();
    Bitmap image1 = mMyFilter.processFilter(scaledBitmap);
    loadFilter(image1);
} else {
    Log.e("Decode image", "Decoded Bitmap is null");
    // Manage the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before applying filter you need to set its width and height for custom scaling then you can apply **zomato**(basic image processing  library) filters on your bitmap image otherwise it will give you error.

```
 public static void filterApply(Filter filter){
    Bitmap bitmcopy = PhotoModel.getInstance().getPhotoCopyBitmap();
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmcopy, bitmcopy.getWidth()-1, bitmcopy.getHeight()-1, false);
    filter.processFilter(scaledBitmap);
    filterImage.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
}
```